# UITEXTFIELD nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have been learning swift and have written a little code to process a string which was working up until a few days ago when I built some extra scenes and then it stopped working. I seem to be getting an error due to my UITEXTFIELD's returning nil but have not been able to solve it.

The code at the moment is just to take a variable and split it up in to relevant sections and display in text fields where the user will have the option to edit before submitting. At the moment I am just using a fixed variable but later on the idea is that the user would be able to input a unique variable to be processed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var FirstNameResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var LastNameResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var BookingRefrenceResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var DepartureAirportResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var DestinationAirportResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AirlineResponse: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var DateResponse: UITextField!
@IBAction func FakeAScan(sender: AnyObject) {
    var QRData = "M1ATILLA/KARACADAG REFNUM LGWDLMTCX2222 086Y004D0091 147>1182"
}

func updateUI() {
    FirstNameResponse.text = FirstName
    LastNameResponse.text = LastName
    BookingRefrenceResponse.text = BookingREF
    DepartureAirportResponse.text = Departure
    DestinationAirportResponse.text = Destination
    AirlineResponse.text = Airline
    DateResponse.text = JulianDate
}

}

extension String {
var condensedWhitespace: String {
    let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
}
}


// remove extra spaces
var QRData = "M1TODD/ANNABEL         HYUWRA LPALGWTOM4681 086Y004D0091 147>1182  6074BTOM000000000000029754010916488701  ".condensedWhitespace

// split in to arrays based on spaces
var QRBreakup = QRData.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var Part1 = QRBreakup[0]
var BookingREF = QRBreakup[1] // Passenger booking refrence
var Part3 = QRBreakup[2]
var Part4 = QRBreakup[3]


// Remove Format & Leg code
var Part1startIndex = Part1.startIndex.advancedBy(2)
var NMSURNM = Part1.substringFromIndex(Part1startIndex)


// Seperate First & Last name
var NAME = NMSURNM.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
var LastName = NAME[0]
var FirstName = NAME[1]


// Seperate Departure Airport, Destination Airport, Airline & Flight number
var Part3temp = Part3 as NSString
var Departure = Part3temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
var Destination = Part3temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 3, length: 3))
var Airline = Part3temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 6, length: 3))
var FlightNum = Part3temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 9, length: 4))


// Seperate Date, Cabin, Seat
var Part4temp = Part4 as NSString
var JulianDate = Part4temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 3))
var Cabin = Part4temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 3, length: 1))
var Seat = Part4temp.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 4, length: 4))
```

It's probably not the cleanest or best way to write this script but just trying to experiment at the moment so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the comment's so far. Below is some more information based on what I understand and can answer.

**The error:**

On line updateUI()
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

self    BoardPassReader.ViewController  0x00007fbd58480770
UIKit.UIViewController  UIViewController
FirstNameResponse   UITextField!    nil None
LastNameResponse    UITextField!    nil None
BookingRefrenceResponse UITextField!    nil None
DepartureAirportResponse    UITextField!    nil None
DestinationAirportResponse  UITextField!    nil None
AirlineResponse UITextField!    nil None
DateResponse    UITextField!    nil None

**Other Information**

@Duncan C
I did read about broken outlet links when I was searching for a solution. Just checked again and they are all showing connected under "Referencing Outlets" on each UITextField.
As far as how the view controller is loaded if I understand correctly it is from the storyboard.

It all seemed to work before I introduced more scenes. I also set all the additional scenes to the same ViewController class.

From the error it implies that it is because the .text values are returning a "nil" value. I wondered if this was because it was trying to set these before it had done the splitting in my script and had assigned values to "FirstName" etc. But that still doesn't explain why it was working before.

Hope the extra information helps.

Comment: all IBOutlet are properly connected

Comment: Check your outlets in the storyboard, just right click on each UITextField in IB and check if there is an outlet connection present.

Comment: not the solution but: variables and functions are written in camelCase :-P

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving fro the console?

Comment: Please don't use capital letter initials for variable and parameter name4s. It just makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have a broken outlet link. If you open the storyboard in IB, select the view controller object, and display the connections inspector it will show you all the view objects defined in your view controller and any outlet connections that are in force.

### EDIT:

P.S. When you ask a question you should post a thorough, complete description of the problem and provide all relevant information. In this case, we need to know the precise error message, the line that's generating it, and we need to know information about how the view controller in question is loaded. Is it loaded from a storyboard or a nib? How are the outlets set up?

Comment: maybe he connected the outlets but they don't have `superview` initially so literally the outlets will be released immediately after the _nib_ loaded, because the `weak` references are not keeping them alive.

Comment: @holex, If he's loading the view controller from a Storyboard I don't think it's possible to create views that don't have a superview. I guess that would be possible from a nib, but we are engaged in speculation at this point. We need the OP to provide more information.

Comment: _if_ he loads it from storyboard; but there is no guarantee for that, we just _assume_ that it is loaded from there.

Comment: Sorry more information added above to original question.